# Оптимизировать решение на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем здравствуйте,решаю задачи на Python.Хочу максимально улучшить свои навыки, сама задача внизу и мое решение. Пожалуйста помогите улучшить мой код:

Напишите функцию `convert(L)`, принимающую на вход список, состоящий из чисел и строк вида:

```
[1, 2, '3', '4', '5', 6]
```

и возвращающую список целых чисел (в том же порядке):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def convert(L):
    a = L
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if type(a[i]) == str:
            a[i] = int(a[i])
    return a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше решение можно оптимизировать с использованием встроенной функции `map()` и `list()`

```
def convert(L):
    return list(map(int, L))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо